# undefined method `rails_admin_controller?' for any controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I've put `check_authorization unless: :rails_admin_controller?` in *ApplicationController* and get **NoMethodError**: `undefined method 'rails_admin_controller?'` for any controller.

I've already set up RailsAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the rails_admin_controller method yourself.

```
check_authorization unless: :rails_admin_controller?
private
def rails_admin_controller?
  self < RailsAdminController
end
```

Comment: ```rails_admin_controller?``` is already defined. see https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/controllers/rails_admin/application_controller.rb#L80

Comment: Touche. Can you output all available ApplicationController.instance_methods and see if it's included or not?

Comment: Go into rails console and run ApplicationController.instance_methods.grep /rails_admin/ -- See if RailsAdmin methods are available, and if the gem is being loaded in the app.

Comment: As expected there is no such method

Comment: You could have your controller inherit from that application controller class. MyController < RailsAdmin::ApplicationController.Or, not sure if this would work --> `include RailsAdmin::ApplicationController` inside your ApplicationController.

Comment: I've tried both solutions already - both are invalid:
```uninitialized constant ApplicationController``` when extends
and can't include class.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still need this I solved it the following way:

```
check_authorization :unless => is_a?(RailsAdmin::MainController)
```